# changes to the model is not applied to the database

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

After setting up a table model in the following code:
http://codepad.org/nAUt68p1

changes to the model is not applied to the database.

In eric python IDE(In other IDE may not found this error),after edited the data item,it shows the following error:

```
QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
```

anyone can help me fix this problem ?thanks !

Comment: Your code is broken. Please do not forget to specify all the parameters to avoid NoneType exceptions. You made the same mistake here several weeks ago. :)

Comment: So why would you like to replace the _id_ with the _annual_ salaries? Is that intentional?

Comment: I am using Python 3.3 + PyQt 4.10.3，and you ?